# How to generate coredump in CentOS (php-fpm)

Tags: php, linux, centos, coredump

I have this setting in www.conf (php-fpm):
rlimit_core = unlimited

Also I have this command:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

and my setting is:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/tmp/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid
1
```

In error.log I have:

```
child 26279 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 522.834434 seconds from start
```

It tells me that a core was dumped, but I didn't find coredump in /tmp

How can I generate coredump file and find it?

Answer (score 0):

I find it in /tmp/systemd-private-bc833f133c6449c6bb1ebe9850277d66-php-fpm.service-zKMT4i/tmp/